# SQLite-net-pcl - SQLite.SQLiteException: Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I seem to be hitting all sorts of problems today. I simply cannot get Sqlite-net-pcl to behave correctly when signing an APK. Debug and release work fine but everytime I create a signed version of the APK the app crashes with this issue:-

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column
```

Here is an example of my model:-

```
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using System;

namespace App.BusinessLayer.LocalObjects
{
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class LocalTip
{

public int ID { get; set; }

[PrimaryKey, Column("tipObjectId")]
public string objectId { get; set; }
public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Bet { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Rating { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; }
public string Bookies { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
public int Status { get; set; }
public Double Odds { get; set; }
public int Outcome { get; set; }

public LocalTip()
{
    this.objectId = " ";
    this.Title = " ";
    this.Bet = " ";
    this.Description = " ";
    this.Rating = " ";
    this.Time = " ";
    this.Bookies = " ";
    this.Url = " ";
}
}
}
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Strange thing is the app crashes when it loads with the above issue. If you go to Applications and Clear Data for this app, it works perfect then?

Comment: You can't add a Primary Key column to an already existing table

Comment: When you delete the application, the database is deleted and the table is created from scratch with the correct primary key column

Comment: @redent84 Okay so situation... I clear the data from my app, uninstall the app from my device. I then install the APK again, loads the app, it crashes. I then go to application settings and delete storage of the app and it works. Hence why I'm so confused on this one.

Comment: Check it out, it seems to be Android v7 that it's crashing with maybe. I accidentally uploaded it to the Play Store as it wasn't doing the same on a V6. The apps called FiveStarTips. I really don't get how this is happening. @redent84